# Disable arrow key scrolling in users browser

Tags: javascript, canvas, scroll, arrow-keys

I'm making a game using canvas, and javascript.

When the page is longer than the screen (comments, etc.) pressing the down arrow scrolls the page down, and makes the game impossible to play.

What can I do to prevent the window from scrolling when the player just wants to move down?

I guess with Java games, and such, this is not a problem, as long as the user clicks on the game.

I tried the solution from: [How to disable page scrolling in FF with arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020414/how-to-disable-page-scrolling-in-ff-with-arrow-keys) ,but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 207, accepted):

## Summary

Simply [prevent the default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) browser action:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if(["Space","ArrowUp","ArrowDown","ArrowLeft","ArrowRight"].indexOf(e.code) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

If you need to support Internet Explorer or other older browsers, use `e.keyCode` instead of `e.code`, but keep in mind that [`keyCode` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#browser_compatibility) and you need to use actual codes instead of strings:

```js
// Deprecated code!
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    // space and arrow keys
    if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

## Original answer

I used the following function in my own game:

```
var keys = {};
window.addEventListener("keydown",
    function(e){
        keys[e.code] = true;
        switch(e.code){
            case "ArrowUp": case "ArrowDown": case "ArrowLeft": case "ArrowRight":
            case "Space": e.preventDefault(); break;
            default: break; // do not block other keys
        }
    },
false);
window.addEventListener('keyup',
    function(e){
        keys[e.code] = false;
    },
false);
```

The magic happens in [`e.preventDefault();`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault). This will block the default action of the event, in this case moving the viewpoint of the browser.

If you don't need the current button states you can simply drop `keys` and just discard the default action on the arrow keys:

```
var arrow_keys_handler = function(e) {
    switch(e.code){
        case "ArrowUp": case "ArrowDown": case "ArrowLeft": case "ArrowRight": 
            case "Space": e.preventDefault(); break;
        default: break; // do not block other keys
    }
};
window.addEventListener("keydown", arrow_keys_handler, false);
```

Note that this approach also enables you to remove the event handler later if you need to re-enable arrow key scrolling:

```
window.removeEventListener("keydown", arrow_keys_handler, false);
```

#### References

- MDN: [`window.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- MDN: [`window.removeEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener)
- MDN: [`KeyboardEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) interface

Comment: I really like this solution, but it doesn't seem to work in chrome =/

Comment: @Kaninepete: There was a syntax error, I used `lC.keys` instead of `keys` in the keyup listener. Fixed this and tested it in Firefox and Chrome. Notice that all changes to `keys` are optional, but since you are building a game...

Comment: in some older (mobile) browsers, it seems that the arrow keys don't even fire key events... :-(

Comment: Actually, I tried several; seems the default WebKit action is to make the arrow keys perform UI operations.

Comment: If you do this, and you have any field inputs on your web page then it you won't be able to use the spacebar or the arrow keys to navigate the text.  Big drawback I found.

Comment: @SingleEntity Well, that's an obvious drawback. On the other hand, you seldom have inputs on games that aren't handled by the game logic itself. That being said, you can simply disable the listener as long as the focus is on an interactive element, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13570007/once-disable-arrow-key-scrolling-in-users-browser-how-to-enable-it?lq=1.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I have had to do

Comment: Note that you really need to use `keydown` and not `keyup`.

Comment: this still doesnt work in chrome :( RIP my snake game

Comment: If you're trying this solution, and it isn't working. Confirm you're actually using the `keydown` and not another key event like `keyup`.

Comment: To anyone trying to use keyCode https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode is deprecated. use code instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code

Answer (score 7):

For maintainability, I would attach the "blocking" handler on the element itself (in your case, the canvas).

```
theCanvas.onkeydown = function (e) {
    if (e.key === 'ArrowUp' || e.key === 'ArrowDown') {
        e.view.event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Why not simply do `window.event.preventDefault()`? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) states:

> `window.event` is a proprietary Microsoft Internet Explorer property
>   which is only available while a DOM event handler is being called. Its
>   value is the Event object currently being handled.

Further readings:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/view
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key

Comment: I've been fighting this for hours and you fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I've tried different ways of blocking scrolling when the arrow keys are pressed, both jQuery and native Javascript - they all work fine in Firefox, but don't work in recent versions of Chrome.
Even the explicit `{passive: false}` property for `window.addEventListener`, which is recommended as the only working solution, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4770179/5589126).

In the end, after many tries, I found a way that works for me in both Firefox and Chrome:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.target.localName != 'input') {   // if you need to filter <input> elements
        switch (e.keyCode) {
            case 37: // left
            case 39: // right
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            case 38: // up
            case 40: // down
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}, {
    capture: true,   // this disables arrow key scrolling in modern Chrome
    passive: false   // this is optional, my code works without it
});
```

Quote for `EventTarget.addEventListener()` from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Syntax)

> **options** Optional
>    An options object specifies characteristics about the event listener. The available options are:
>
> > **capture**
> >    A `Boolean` indicating that events of this type will be dispatched to the registered `listener` before being dispatched to any `EventTarget` beneath it in the DOM tree.
> > **once**
> >    ...
> > **passive**
> >    A `Boolean` that, if true, indicates that the function specified by `listener` will never call `preventDefault()`. If a passive listener does call `preventDefault()`, the user agent will do nothing other than generate a console warning. ...

Answer (score 0):

This is the accepted answer rewritten for React.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const usePreventKeyboardScrolling = () => {
  const onKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (
      ["Space", "ArrowUp", "ArrowDown", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowRight"].indexOf(
        e.code
      ) > -1
    ) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown);
  });
};

export { usePreventKeyboardScrolling };
```