# disable horizontal scrolling with css

Tags: css

I know you can disable horizontal scrolling with

```
overflow-x:hidden;
```

but what about when the uers press the scroll button on the mouse and moves the page that way, or when they use the arrow keys, how can I disable that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for the arrow keys you can make the browser prevent the default action of them using JavaScript.

```
var arrow_keys_handler = function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case 37: case 39: case 38:  case 40: // Arrow keys
        case 32: e.preventDefault(); break; // Space
        default: break; // do not block other keys
    }
};
window.addEventListener("keydown", arrow_keys_handler, false);
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916620/disable-arrow-key-scrolling-in-users-browser).

**EDIT**: A more elegant solution is to place your content in a container with `overflow-x:hidden` applied. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ub4dv/

Comment: Thank you, that works for arrow keys any ideas about the mouse click?