# Disabling a key used for a Jquery animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

So I am using the down arrow key to set off a Jquery .animate() function. Currently, when the down arrow key is pressed, it does the animation, but also moves the browser page down. Is there a way for me to disable the downward movement set into action by pressing the down arrow key, but also have it call the .animate() function? My animate function is below..

```
<script>
$(document).on('keyup',function(evt) {
    if (event.which == 40) {
        alert('down key was pressed');
    }
});
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `evt.preventDefault()` ? Also, your `event.which` should be `evt.which`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable arrow key scrolling in users browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916620/disable-arrow-key-scrolling-in-users-browser)

Comment: I think you'd want to preventDefault on the keydown, not the keyup... the browser's native scrolling behavior is likely happen when the key is pressed not when it's released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent normal behavior by using `event.preventDefault()`

```
<script>
$(document).on('keydown',function(evt) {
    if (evt.which == 40) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        alert('down key was pressed');
    }
});
</script>
```

that should do the trick

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for.