# Disable Left and Right keys in JQuery Steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-steps

I have a Jquery Steps form that contains three steps.
I want in the last step to disable the left and right keys so I can stay in the same step.

```
$(function() {
  form_prop = $("#new_prop").show();
  form_prop.steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    onStepChanging: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {

      if (currentIndex == 2) {
        form_prop.on('keyDown', function(event) {
          const key = event.key; // "ArrowRight", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowUp", or "ArrowDown"
          if (key == "ArrowRight" || key == "ArrowLeft") {
            // Disable Next and previous
          }
        });
      }
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: Nice answer here:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916620/disable-arrow-key-scrolling-in-users-browser)

Comment: Yes I used event.preventDefault() but I still have the same problem, it still change the steps when I hit the left or the right arrow key.

Answer (score 4):

Set `enableKeyNavigation` to `false` in jquery.steps.js.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the optional setting of Smart Wizard. If you already have this method

```
$('#smartwizard').smartWizard({
```

Add following block to it

```
keyboardSettings: {
      keyNavigation: false, // Enable/Disable keyboard navigation(left and right keys are used if enabled)
  },
```

If you don't have that method, just add it to your page javascript.

```
 $('#smartwizard').smartWizard({
     keyboardSettings: {
          keyNavigation: false, // Enable/Disable keyboard navigation(left and right keys are used if enabled)
      },
 });
```

Hope this helped.

Comment: Wow, had no idea that the official documentation is wrong about it techlaboratory.net/jquery-smartwizard

Answer (score 1):

I'd try :

```
$(function() {
  form_prop = $("#new_prop").show();
  form_prop.steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    onStepChanging: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {

      if (currentIndex == 2) {
        form_prop.on('keyDown', function(event) {
          const key = event.key; // "ArrowRight", "ArrowLeft", "ArrowUp", or "ArrowDown"
          if (key == "ArrowRight" || key == "ArrowLeft") {
            event.preventDefault();// Disable Next and previous
          }
        });
      }
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: I already used event.preventDefault(), but I still have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

From the docs i see that you can `return false` from the `onStepChanging` event to cancel the change.

So

```
$(function() {
  form_prop = $("#new_prop").show();
  form_prop.steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    onStepChanging: function(event, currentIndex, newIndex) {

      if (currentIndex == 2) {
          return false;
      }
    }

  });
});
```

Should work.

Comment: Yes it works, but I want it only if the user hit the Left or the Right arrow Key, because when I write in a textarea and I hit the left or the right arrow key, it changes the steps

Comment: So, you have other way to navigate which you want to continue using. Although it should not navigate away when the focus is in an element. There is an option `suppressPaginationOnFocus` for that that is by defauly `true` so it should not be happening. Are you using the latest version ?

Comment: Yes, I have the v1.1.0

Comment: @Amir do you have a live example that demonstrates the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

First Make sure that `jquery.steps.js` is included.
If `jquery.steps.min.js` is included replace it by `jquery.steps.js`
Open the `jquery.steps.js` file change `enableKeyNavigation` to `false`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VAxD.png)