# Trying to start/trigger an iframe with a JS game only when needed in my HTML5 page

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I've learned the basic of HTML5, CSS and a little of JS.
I'm trying to make a site where I can show my projects and knowledge.
The thing is, I want to put 2 JS games that I made in the page, but I don't want them to load instantly with the page. so, I would like it to load only when I click on it.

The game: https://editor.p5js.org/snufupugos/full/jm8j5k5pC

How I got it on the page:

```
<section class="games"> <iframe src="https://editor.p5js.org/snufupugos/embed/jm8j5k5pC" class="freeway" title="Remake Freeway"></iframe> </section>
```

The CSS:

```
.freeway{
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
margin: 2em auto;
border: 2px solid #801edb;
border-radius: 50px;
border-width: thick;
padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

My first Idea was to use an image, and then the hover to transform to the iframe, but I think it is not possible since it did not work.

Anyway, can someone help me with this? Any Idea how to do it?

Thank you.

Comment: 'Hi what is the 'it' that you want to click on to get the game to load? Will there be, for example, something in the iframe place the user can see, like a poster for the game? When 'it' is clicked, write the src of the iframe (and remove the 'poster' if there was one).

Comment: "or example, something in the iframe place the user can see, like a poster for the game? When 'it' is clicked, write the src of the iframe (and remove the 'poster' if there was one)"
Yes! This is exactly what I had in mind. There is a way to do it?

Also, I'm open to other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function start(){
  document.getElementById("frame").src = "https://editor.p5js.org/snufupugos/embed/jm8j5k5pC";
  document.getElementById("imgs").remove();
        
        var news = document.createElement("img");
        news.setAttribute('id', 'stop');
        news.setAttribute('onclick', 'stop();');
        news.setAttribute('class', 'button');
        news.setAttribute('width', '25px');
        news.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAgAAAAIACAYAAAD0eNT6AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAAOxAAADsQBlSsOGwAAABl0RVh0U29mdHdhcmUAd3d3Lmlua3NjYXBlLm9yZ5vuPBoAACAASURBVHic7d13mJ11nffxdya9h4QQaUY6gkuVtqCAgKJSBMWurJVVdxd0fR52n8ttuuuqq4uuXdeKa0FcG4oIUpQICKGIJCAgXQggKSQhbZLnj98MmUymnHLf9/cu79d13dcZJufc5xMY5vc9vzoGSWU3Hpjbd80DZvVd2wz4eiYwFZjS9zih73vj+h4HmtZ3z4HWAysHfW8Z0AssB9YBq4DVfY/LBl1L+x4fBR7re9zQ8d9YUu7GRAeQGm4usFPfNX/A1zsC27G54a+i/kLgMeBB4KG+x/uAB/q+fjwsndRwFgBSvsYCzwR2A3bvu3Yb8Dg5LlopPAXcBdzd9zjw6/uBjXHRpHqzAJCyswOwD7DvgMcDSF3yat86UiFwG7BowOPtpKEJSV2wAJDaNx7YEzh4wHUgafxd+VsP3AksHHDdSJqfIKlFFgDSyMYCzwYOA44ADu3753GRobSVDaTegd8A1wLX9f2zQwjSMCwApC3NAI4CjgQOBw4BpocmUqdWANeTCoIFwNXAk6GJpBKxAFDTTSd9uj+e1PAfytZL5FQPvcAdpELgMuAKXIWgBrMAUNNMJjX0J/Rd++P/B021EbgFuLTvuhpYE5pIKpC/+NQE+wEnsvlTftOX3mloTwG/IhUDlwC3xsaR8mUBoDqaRGrojwdOI83Yl9p1H6kQuIhUFNg7oFqxAFBdzAFO6btOwLX3ytYq4OfAj/quJ2LjSN2zAFCVbQu8BDgDeBFO3lMxekkrC74LXAA8HBtH6owFgKpmHvBKUqN/JNATG0cN10taYnhB3/VYbBypdRYAqoLJwEnAG/GTvsqrv2fg68C3cM8BlZwFgMpqHGnm/huAk3HmvqplNWmuwDeAn+HZBSohCwCVzV7Aa4C/IB2PK1Xdw6T5Al8CfhucRXqaBYDKYDrwauBNpP32pbpaAHwF+A6wMjiLGs4CQJH2Jn3SfzuwTWwUqVBPkuYJfIa0G6FUOAsAFW0CcCqp0T8OfwalhcAXgPNJuxFKhfCXr4qyA/BOUsM/NziLVEaPkgqBz+DeAiqABYDydhBwFmkJ36TgLFIVrAN+CJwHXBOcRZLa0gO8gjThaZOXl1fH16+A03HDK0klN4H0SX8x8b84vbzqdN0NnI29aMqQQwDKwnTgzcB7gZ2Cs0h1tgT4HPBxYFlwFlWcBYC6MRt4N/DXwMzgLFKTLAP+i1QILA3OooqyAFAn5pAa/bOBWcFZpCZbCXwa+AgeUaw2WQCoHf0N/zn4iV8qk5XAl4EPkoYJpFFZAKgV04B3AX+PDb9UZv09Av8OLA/OopIbGx1ApTYBeAvwfeBlOANZKrsJwFHA20gf8BYCG0ITSaqUcaSG/37ilz95eXl1ft1HOmTLD3vaikMAGux44GPAftFBJGXmdtKKnZ9FB1F5WACo3z6kmcQvjQ4iKTcXkSbx3h0dRPHsFtIOpLXEXwD2Cs4iKV97ks7mmAZcRzp3QA1lAdBc40lL+r4HHI69QVJTjGPzRMF1wA2k+QJqGH/pN9NxpF3E9okOIincjaT5Ab+MDqJiecJUs+wMfB24DBt/SclBwFXAj4FdgrOoQA4BNMM44P8CFwIHB2eRVE57koYF1gO/ATbGxlHeHAKov/2B/waeGx1EUmXcQioGro8OovzYA1Bfk4H3AeeTuv4lqVXPIG0gtC3wK1KvgGrGHoB6ej4u65OUjT+Qlg5eFh1E2XISYL3MAj4PXImNv6Rs7Ar8nDSBeE5wFmXIIYD6OBn4KXAs9uxIytYY0nyiM4FHSXMEVHE2FNW3A/BZ4JToIJIa4wfAO4GHo4OocxYA1fYy4IukiTqSVKTHgbcCP4wOos44B6CaJgOfAL6Pjb+kGNuSegK+TjpbQBVjD0D1PBf4Bk7yk1QedwCvAxZGB1HrnARYHWOAs4FvA/OCs0jSQNsCbya1Kb/Cw4UqwR6Aaujfw/+Y4BySNJorgDcCD0YH0cicA1B+LwduxsZfUjUcC/wOeG10EI3MAqC8pgNfJR3gMzs2iiS1ZSbwP8CXcIJgaTkEUE57Av8L7BsdRJK6dAdwOrAoOoi2ZA9A+ZxCOorTxl9SHewFXAu8IjqItuQqgPIYC/wTaVe/ScFZJClLE4EzSHuYXIGrBErBIYBymAN8CzghOogk5exK4FWkMwUUyAIg3oGk8f5nBeeQpKI8QBoS+E10kCZzDkCsNwILsPGX1Cw7A78knSWgIBYAMSaS9vL/GmlMTJKaZiLpMLOv4+/BEA4BFG970gEah0YHkaSSuBY4DXgkOkiTWAAUa1/gJ8D86CCSVDIPAS8FbokO0hQOARTnOOBqbPwlaSg7kg4SOjE6SFO4D0Ax/gL4DjA1OIckldlE4NXAEjxaOHcWAPkaA/wzcB7+u5akVvQAJ5POQLkkOEutOQcgPxNIB2G8PjqIJFXUBcCZwJroIHVkAZCPbUib+xwTnEOSqm4B8DLg8eggdWMBkL1dgJ8Ce0cHkaSauAt4CXBndJA6cRVAtg4hrWe18Zek7OxOWiFwUHSQOrEAyM7RwGXAdtFBJKmG5gGXA0dGB6kLC4BsnAxcDMyIDiJJNTYT+DmenJoJC4DuvQ74Hu5lLUlFmAL8mLR1sLrg2vTunA18Hv89SlKRxgGnA3cAtwVnqSwbrs69F/hPXEkhSRHGkoqAB4GbgrNUkgVAZ84FPhIdQpIargc4BVhOWoGlNlgAtO9c4EPRISRJQOqFPRHYBFwVnKVSLADa837gA9EhJElbOZY0Gfuy6CBVYQHQun8F3hcdQpI0rKNIwwJXBueoBAuA1vwL8A/RISRJozoaWAtcHR2k7CwARvde4N+iQ0iSWnY88CRwTXSQMrMAGNl7gI9Gh5Akte2FwB+BG6ODlJUFwPDOBs6LDiFJ6sgY0gmCt+NmQUNyE5uhvR74Gm6VLElVtx54OWn7YA1gAbC1U0h7+4+LDiJJysQ64FTgZ9FBysQCYEvHAj8FJkUHkSRlajXwYuCX0UHKwgJgs0OAXwDTo4NIknKxHHgBTgwELAD67UJaLjIvOogkKVePA0cAd0UHieYkN5gNXIyNvyQ1wbbAj4BtooNEa3oBMB64ANgrOogkqTDPBn4ATIwOEqnJBcAY4EvAcdFBJEmFez7wVRo8FN7kjYA+APx1dAhJUpjn9D1eGRkiSlMLgDcBH4sOIUkKdzRwL3BLcI7CNbHr4xjgEmBCcA5JUjmsJ20bfFl0kCI1rQDYB1gAzIoOIkkqlRXAUcCt0UGK0qQCYHvSWv/50UEkSaV0L2mPgEeCcxSiKasAJpKWfNj4S5KG8yzg+zRkiLgpkwA/B5wcHUKSVHo7AXOBn0QHyVsTCoA3kJb8SZLUiucCDwA3RQfJU93nABxImvQ3OTqIJKlS1gDPA26IDpKXOhcAs0n/4XaJDiJJqqT7gYNJBwjVTl0nAfYA38TGX5LUuWcC36amw+W1/EsBHwLOjA4hSaq8XYFxwOXRQbJWxyGAU0nLOOr4d5MkFW8TcAbwveggWapbI7kX8BtgRnQQSVKtPAkcBiyODpKVOs0BmE7a7MfGX5KUtenAd4Fp0UGyUqc5AF8Ajo8OIUmqre2AecCPooNkoS4FwMuBD0aHkCTV3kHA7cBt0UG6VYc5ADuRznGeHR1EktQIy4D9SfsEVFbV5wD0AF/Dxl+SVJxZwPlUvBe90uGBvwPeGh1CktQ484GVwK+jg3SqykMABwHX0JBjGyVJpbMeOBK4PjpIJ6paAEwFFpLW/UuSFGUx6fTA1dFB2lXVIYBPAy+MDiFJary5pHloP4kO0q4q9gC8jLTVryRJZXEqFdsfoGoFwA7Ab4E50UEkSRrgMWA/4JHoIK2q2jLAT2PjL0kqn7nAF6NDtKNKcwBeCfxDdAhJkoaxJ3AncGt0kFZUZQhgJrCINAQgSVJZ/QnYF1gSHWQ0VRkCOA8bf0lS+c0BPhkdohVV6AE4FvgF1cgqSRLAGcCF0SFGUvZGdQpp1v9u0UEkSWrDI8A+wNLoIMMp+yTADwInRYeQJKlN04AZlHiDoDL3AOxP2l95fHQQSZI6sBF4HiU9MKisBcA44DrSgT+SJFXV70ht2froIIOVdQjgXOD10SEkSerSdqRjgxdEBxmsjD0Au5IqpsnRQSRJysBq4NnA/dFBBirjPgDnYeMvSaqPKcDHokMMVrYegBOAn0eHkCQpBycCl0SH6FemAmACac3/XtFBJEnKwSLgAEoyIbBMkwDfC7w6OoQkSTmZS9oY6NroIFCeHoAdgDtIGydIklRXK0inBoYfFlSWHoBPAIdFh5AkKWcTSTsEXhQdpAw9APsDCylPMSJJUp56gQOBWyNDlGEZ4H9g4y9Jao6xwEeiQ0QXAC8lLf2TJKlJTgReFBkgcghgLHALsG9gBkmSoiwiDYNviHjzyB6AN2PjL0lqrn0IPPcmqgdgEvB7YOeg95ckqQzuI22At7boN47qAXgXNv6SJM0H3h7xxhE9ANOBu0hHJEqS1HSPAbsBTxb5phE9AP8HG39JkvrNBf6m6DctugdgW+APpF4ASZKULAd2IZ0VUIiiewD+Fht/SZIGmwmcU+QbFtkDMAe4BwsASZKGUmgvQJE9AO/Bxl+SpOHMBM4u6s2K6gGYTfr0P6Og95MkqYoK6wUoqgfg3dj4S5I0mpkUtCKgiB6AGaSdjmYV8F6SJFXdUuCZwMo836SIHoB3YOMvSVKrtgHelPeb5N0DMJG07n+HnN9HkqQ6uQfYA+jN6w3y7gE4Ext/SZLatQtwWp5vkGcPwFhgMamCkSRJ7bkeODSvm+fZA3AaNv6SJHXqEOCovG6eZwHwnhzvLUlSE/xtXjfOawjgYOCGnO4tSVJTbAT2BW7P+sZ59QD46V+SpO71kNPGQHn0AOxAWr4wIYd7S5LUNE8B84HHsrxpHj0A78TGX5KkrEwmbaqXqax7ACYCDwBzM76vJElNtoS0PfC6rG6YdQ/AGdj4S5KUtXnA6VneMOsC4C8zvp8kSUoybWOzHALYB7gtw/tJkqQt/RnwuyxulGUPwF9leC9JkrS1t2V1o6x6AKYBDwEzMrqfJEna2nJgR2BVtzfKqgfgNdj4S5KUt5mkCfddy6oAeHNG95EkSSN7UxY3yWIIYE/SHsV5Hi0sSZKSTaS2965ubpJFD8BbsPGXJKkoY4Azs7hJN8YB9wPbdxtEkiS17CHS+QC9nd6g2x6AE7HxlySpaDsCx3Vzg24LgDd0+XpJktSZrtrgboYApgOPAFO6CSBJkjqyinRGQEd7AnTTA3A6Nv6SJEWZCpzc6Yu7KQBe08VrJUlS917b6Qs7HQLYjjQDcVynbyxJkrq2njQZ/0/tvrDTHoBXYeMvSVK08cArOnlhNwWAJEmK98pOXtTJEMA84I9ke5SwJEnqTC9pGOCxdl7USTf+adj4q3pWABcBVwC3APcCy0jjZ2qu8cAs4FnAAcCxwEmkZc5SVYwFTgG+lPcbXUo6iMDLqwrX7aTTKicjtWYK6YyT3xP/8+vl1er1U9rU7hDAHNLmP04AVNmtBv4R+ASwITiLqmk8cDbwAWBScBZpNOtIQ/TLWn1Bu135p2Djr/K7EzgM+Bg2/urceuCjwDHAw7FRpFFNoM1NgdotAE5t8/lS0W4CjgR+Fx1EtXEdcAhp7ohUZqe08+R2hgAmAY+Tth6UyuhOUuPf1kxYqUU7Ab/BE1BVXiuAuaThgFG10wPwAmz8VV5rgDOw8Vd+HiR1sT4VHUQaxgzg+a0+uZ0C4KXtZ5EK8z7solX+FgL/Hh1CGsFJrT6xnSGAe4H5bUeR8vd7YF+c8KdiTCUNNzkUoDK6C9ijlSe22gOwHzb+Kq8PY+Ov4qwC3h8dQhrG7sDerTyx1QLgxM6zSLlaAXw7OoQa5+vAk9EhpGG8qJUntVoAHN9FEClPPyFt+iMVaTUd7LwmFeSFrTyplQJgMvC87rJIubk8OoAay589ldXRpI2BRtRKAXAUboOp8nLmv6L8NjqANIypwJ+P9qRWCoATus8i5eae6ABqrD9EB5BGMGrbbQGgqlsRHUCNtTw6gDSCUdvu0fYBmE3aWa3dMwOkorR7oqWUpU3RAaRhbCSd4Dvs6YCjNezPb+E5kiSpXHpIZ6OM+ISRtLynsCRJKpUR2/DRCoCjMwwiSZKKM2IbPtL46QzgCWBspnGkbDkHQJGcA6Ay20CayzfkrpUj9QAchY2/JElVNQ44fLg/HKkAGHHygCRJKr2jhvuDkQqAI3IIIkmSijNsD8Bw46c9wFLSPACpzJwDoEjOAVDZLSfNA9g4+A+G6wF4Djb+kiRV3Uxg76H+YLgC4LD8skiSpAINOQxgASBJUr0N2aYPVwAcmmMQSZJUnCHb9KEmUE0inbA2Ptc4UjacBKhITgJUFawnzetbM/CbQ/UA7IeNvyRJdTEe2GfwN4cqAA7MP4skSSrQVm27BYAkSfVnASBJUgNt1bYPnkA1lnRq0ORC4kjdcxKgIjkJUFWxkrQp0NM7Ag7uAdgNG39JkupmGjB/4DcGFwD7FpdFkiQVaIs2fnABsNUyAUmSVAtbtPEWAJIkNYMFgCRJDbRFGz9wBnUPaZagkwBVJa4CUCRXAahKVpK2BN4EW/YAzMfGX5KkupoG7Nj/DwMLgN2LzyJJkgr0dFtvASBJUnMMWQDsFhBEkiQV5+m23h4ASZKawyEASZIa6Om2fsyAx5XAlJA4UudcBqhILgNU1TxJWgr4dA/Attj4S5JUd9OBWbC5ANg5LoskSSrQM8ECQJKkptkZLAAkSWoaewAkSWqgLXoAdgoMIkmSirNFAbBDYBBJklSc7WFzATAvMIgkSSrOPLAAkCSpabaDtIvaeGAt7qimavLnVpHcCVBVtBGY2EOqBPwlKklSM/QAc/oLAEmS1BzzeoC50SkkSVKh5vYA20SnkCRJhZrVQ9+pQJIkqTG2sQdAkqTmmdUDzIxOIUmSCjXTIQBJkppnG3sAJElqnlk9wLToFJIkqVBTe4Ap0SkkSVKhpvQAk6NTSJKkQk22B0CSpOaZYgEgSVLzOAQgSVIDTe4BJkWnkCRJhZrcA4yLTiFJkgo1zgJAkqTmGdsDjI1OIUmSCjXOAkCSpOaxB0CSpAayB0CSpAYa2xOdQJIkFa8H6I0OIUmSCtVrASBJUvNssACQJKl57AGQJKmBNvQAG6JTSJKkQvVaAEiS1DwbeoA10SkkSVKhnuoBnopOIUmSCvVUD7A6OoUkSSrUagsASZKaZ7VDAJIkNY9DAJIkNdDqHmBldApJklSoVT3AsugUkiSpUE9YAEiS1DzLLAAkSWqe5RYAkiQ1z1ILAEmSmmdZD7A0OoUkSSrU8h7gsegUkiSpUEt6gCXRKSRJUqEeHQOMA9YCPcFhpE6MiQ6gRtsUHUDqQC8wsQfYADwRHEaSJBXjcaC3/1P/o5FJJElSYZbA5m5/5wFIktQMj8LmAuDhwCCSJKk4D8PmAuCBwCCSJKk494MFgCRJTfMAWABIktQ0FgCSJDXQFkMA9wcGkSRJxXkAttxFbRUwJSaL1DF3AlQkdwJU1awAZsKW2//+ISaLJEkqyN39XwwsAO4KCCJJkorzdFtvASBJUnMMWQDcPcQTJUlSfQw5BGABIElSvTkHQJKkBnq6rR+4hKoHWAlMLjyO1DmXASqSywBVJSuBGfT93A7sAdgI3B6RSJIk5W4RA4rWniH+UJIk1c8WbbwFgCRJzWABIElSA1kASJLUQFu08YNnUI8lHRTgoUCqClcBKJKrAFQVK0mHAG3s/8bgHoBe4NYiE0mSpNzdzIDGH7YuAABuKiaLJEkqyFZtuwWAJEn1d/PgbwxVANxYQBBJklScrT7cDzWBaiLwJDA+9zhS95wEqEhOAlQVrCNtAbx24DeH6gFYCywuIpEkScrdIgY1/jB0AQBwXb5ZJElSQa4d6psWAJIk1duQbboFgCRJ9TZkD8BwE6h6gCdIuwZJZeYkQEVyEqDKbhkwh0GbAMHwPQAbgRvyTCRJknJ3LUM0/jB8AdD/IkmSVF3DDumPVAAsyCGIJEkqztXD/cFI46fTSfMAxmUeR8qOcwAUyTkAKrP1wDbAqqH+cKQegCcZYu9gSZJUCTcwTOMPIxcAAL/MNoskSSrIiG24BYAkSfU0Yhs+2vjpbOAxRi8UpCjOAVAk5wCorHqBbUn7AAxptIb9CeCWLBNJGZsQHUCNNTE6gDSChYzQ+ENrn+wvzSaLlIsZ0QHUWO6UqjIbte22AFDV7RIdQI21a3QAaQSZFABXA091n0XKxQHRAdRY+0cHkIaxErhmtCe1UgCsAX7VdRwpHy+IDqDGOi46gDSMq4B1oz2p1dn9l3WXRcrNScDU6BBqnKnAi6NDSMP4eStParUAuLiLIFKepgGvjg6hxnkN6WdPKqNLWnlSO2uo7wGe1VEUKV93AvuS9r2W8jYBWATsFh1EGsKdwJ6tPLGdDX4u6iyLlLs9gHOiQ6gx3o2Nv8qr5ba6nQLgJx0EkYryfuDw6BCqvSOAf4kOIY2g5QKgnSGAiaRtgae3HUcqxiPAocAD0UFUSzsAvwF2jA4iDWMFMJcWVgBAez0Aa4FfdJJIKsgzSNXvTtFBVDs7kSZD2/irzC6hxcYf2j/k54dtPl8q2n6kT2kOBygrRwDXk362pDL7UTtPbvcktdmkbtbxbb5OKtoa4N+BjwGrgrOomiYA7wH+GQ/+UfmtA7YDlrf6gnZ7AJ4ArmzzNVKESaTJWncB78DNgtS6qcDbgMWkItLGX1VwGW00/tDZWepnAZ/r4HVSpJWklSxXADeT9rVYRhvjZaqlCcAs0qFSB5C2ln4JbvKj6nkL8OV2XtBJATAPeAgY28FrJUlStjYA2wOPt/OidocAAJYACzp4nSRJyt4VtNn4Q2cFAMB3O3ydJEnK1oWdvKiTIQBIGw38ERjX4eslSVL31pE2qfpTuy/stAfgMTwiWJKkaBfTQeMPnRcAAN/s4rWSJKl73+r0hZ0OAUBaK7sE11dLkhRhFWllXkebnXXTA7AKjwiWJCnK/9LFTqfdFAAA53f5ekmS1Jmu2uBuhgAgbQZ0L56+JklSkR4EngX0dnqDbnsAeoH/6fIekiSpPV+hi8Yfuu8BANgTuD2je0mSpJFtAvYA7u7mJt32AAD8Hrgmg/tIkqTRXUWXjT9kUwBAmycQSZKkjn0li5tk1W0/jXRC4IyM7idJkra2DNgRWN3tjbLqAVgJfCOje0mSpKF9jQwaf8h24t4+wO8yvqckSdrsOcBtWdwoqx4AgEXAggzvJ0mSNruSjBp/yLYAAPhcxveTJElJpm1s1t31E4EHgLkZ31eSpCZbAjwTWJfVDbPuAViLvQCSJGXts2TY+EM+E/a2J50PMCGHe0uS1DRrSfv+P5LlTbPuAQB4GLggh/tKktRE3yTjxh/yW7J3ELAwp3tLktQkBwI3Z33TPHoAAG4Ers7p3pIkNcXl5ND4Q34FAMB5Od5bkqQm+HheN85z174e4FbSDoGSJKk9i0k7/23M4+Z59gBsBP4zx/tLklRnHyKnxh/y37d/POnM4p1zfh9JkurkQWA3Ml77P1CePQAA64H/yvk9JEmqm4+SY+MPxZzcNx24D9imgPeSJKnqngDmAyvzfJO8ewAAngQ+WcD7SJJUBx8n58YfiukBAJhJ2h54VkHvJ0lSFS0nbfu7LO83KqIHANJf6FMFvZckSVX1nxTQ+ENxPQCQPv3fg70AkiQNpbBP/1BcDwCkv9BnCnw/SZKq5DwKavyh2B4AgDnAH4AZBb+vJEllthTYlQILgCJ7AAD+hLsDSpI02H9QYOMPxfcAAEwD7gLmBby3JEll8yiwO2nZfGHGFvlmfdYBG4ATA95bkqSyORe4uug3jegBAJgA3A7sEvT+kiSVwb3A3sDaot84ogcAoBdYAZwa9P6SJJXB2cCNEW8c1QMAqfhYCOwfmEGSpCg3A88lfSguXNGrAAbqBd4d+P6SJEU6h6DGH2ILAIArgO8HZ5AkqWgXAFdFBogcAui3K3AbMCk6iCRJBVgDPJs0ATBM1CTAgZYC04GjooNIklSAD1GC3u8y9ABAKgDuALaPDiJJUo4eIi37WxkdpAw9AJA2B1qKywIlSfX2LuCG6BBQnh4ASBMSrwUOiQ4iSVIOrgOOADZFB4H4VQADbSRtiFCKfzGSJGVoE/BeStTGlakAALiGtDRCkqQ6+QYB+/2PpExDAP3mA4uAKdFBJEnKwErSxL+HooMMVJZJgAMtJ50WeEJ0EEmSMnAucGl0iMHK2AMAMI40IfDg6CCSJHXhetLEv7Atf4dT1gIA0iFB1wPjo4NIktSBDcChwE3RQYZSxiGAfkuAqbhDoCSpmj4IfDM6xHDK3AMAMJF0XOLe0UEkSWrD70k92WuigwynbMsAB1sL/CUlWjcpSdIoNgHvoMSNP5R7CKDffcDOwEHRQSRJasHngU9FhxhN2YcA+s0kHRm8Y3QQSZJG8DCwD7AsOshoyj4E0G85cE50CEmSRvEuKtD4Q3UKAIALKcH5yZIkDaNS7VRVhgD6bQ/8Ftg2OogkSQM8CuxHWsJeCVXqAYA0tvJGXBUgSSqPTcBbqVDjD9VYBTDYXaSegOdGB5EkCfgM8PHoEO2q2hBAvynAQtwgSJIUazHpA+nq6CDtqtoQQL/VwOuAddFBJEmNtRZ4LRVs/KGaQwD9HgbWA8dHB5EkNdK5VGjW/2BVHQLo10M6Y/kF0UEkSY1yKXAisDE6SKeqXgBA2h3wFmBOdBBJUiMsJR3080B0kG5UdQ7AQA8Bb48OIUlqjLOoeOMP1Z4DMNBiYD5wYHQQSVKtfQH4cHSILNRhCKDfNOA60iEMkiRl7VbgCGBVdJAs1KkAANgDuJ50eqAkSVlZBhxC2oyuFuowB2CgO3GrYElStjYBb6ZGjT/UZw7AQHcAE4DnRQeRMjzZdgAACc5JREFUJNXCB4DPRofIWt2GAPr1ABcBL44OIkmqtEtJbUlvdJCs1bUAAJhNmg+wa3QQSVIl3Ufa5//x6CB5qNscgIGeAE6nons0S5JCrQFeTk0bf6h3AQBph8CzokNIkirnnaRTZ2urjpMAB/st8AxSN44kSaP5FPDB6BB5q/McgIEmAlcChwfnkCSV26+BY2nAcfNNKQAA5pL+w+4eHUSSVEr3kHb6WxIdpAh1nwMw0GPAKaRTnCRJGmg5qY1oROMPzSoAIB0adBqwNjqIJKk01pNm/P8uOkiRmjAJcLD7gLtJSwSbNAQiSdpa/za/P4gOUrQmFgCQqrwxwDHBOSRJsf4J+GR0iAhNLQAArgJ2AfaPDiJJCvEt4JzoEFGa3gU+HrgYOC46iCSpUFcBL6LBc8KaXgAAzACuBv4sOogkqRCLgKNo+KowC4DkWcC1wLzgHJKkfD1C2hTuvugg0Zq2DHA49wIvIa0DlSTV0zLS0b6Nb/zBAmCgG4ETgZXRQSRJmVtN2ujn5uggZWEBsKVrgVNJx0BKkurhKeAk4FfRQcrEAmBrlwMvo8EzQyWpRtYDrwSuiA5SNhYAQ7sEeC2wITqIJKljvcAbgYuig5RRkzcCGs1i0kSRU3G1hCRVzSbgLODr0UHKygJgZLcAfyKtEJAkVcMm4K+Az0cHKTMLgNFdT1oeeGJ0EElSS/4e+Hh0iLKzAGjNtaR/V0dHB5EkjehfgH+LDlEFFgCtu4K0PPD46CCSpCF9GHhfdIiqsABozwLSetLjcWKgJJXJP/ZdapEFQPsWAEtIEwMtAiQp1ibg3cBHooNUjQVAZ24A7iZtK+leCpIUoxd4K/C56CBV5CfY7pwKfAeYGB1EkhpmHfA64MLoIFVlAdC9l5B+ACdHB5GkhlgLvAr4YXSQKrMAyMbRwI+B6dFBJKnmVpHOa7ksOkjVWQBk5xDgZ8Ds6CCSVFPLgJcCv44OUgdOYMvO9cAJpBUCkqRsPQK8ABv/zFgAZOtG4HBgUXQQSaqR20i/W2+KDlInFgDZuxc4Es+elqQsXA4cRTqdVRmyAMjHMtLhQR5DKUmd+yrwYtLvVGXMjYDy00taovIUcBxOuJSkVm0C3g+8h/S7VDmwUSrGq0iV7KTgHJJUdutIu/udHx2k7iwAinMk8ANg2+ggklRSS4HTgSuDczSCBUCx9gB+0vcoSdrsHtIa/8XRQZrCSYDFuhN4PnBtdBBJKpFfk5b52fgXyEmAxVsJfI10gNBRwVkkKdoXSPOkVkQHaRqHAGK9Hvg8MCU6iCQVbA3wLuDL0UGaygIg3gHA94Bdo4NIUkHuB15B2kJdQZwDEO9m0kFCl0QHkaQCXAwciI1/OOcAlMNTwP/0Pb4Ae2Yk1c8m4CPAW4DVwVmEDU0ZnUTaAGNWdBBJysgK4C+A7wfn0AAWAOW0B2lewJ9FB5GkLt1O2tzHJX4l4xyAcroT+HPgS9FBJKkLXwSei41/KdkDUH6nkf4nmhMdRJJatAx4B/Dt6CAangVANcwDvkI6FlOSyuwXwJnAQ9FBNDJXAVTDKuCbpIMyjgXGxcaRpK2sB/6VdJKfu/pVgD0A1fMcUjHgBEFJZbEYeB1wU3QQtc4egOp5lDQcMAM4FIs4SbHOB04l7e6nCrHxqLYXkYqB7aODSGqcx0ib+vw4Oog64zLAarsEOAj4UXQQSY3Sv0+JjX+FWQBU3yOk7rdXkipyScrLI8AZpIN8lgRnUZecA1Afi4CvAc8A9g/OIqleNgHfAE4BFgZnUUacA1BPLwc+RSoGJKkbdwBvB34ZHUTZsgegnhYD/w1MIW3D6VCPpHZtAP4DeDVwd3AW5cAegPo7CPg8qRCQpFbcBLwNu/trzR6A+nsY+CqwEjgSGB+aRlKZrQLOJe3m51a+NWcB0AwbgQWkSYJzcZKgpC1tAi4EXkZaXrwpNo6K4BBAMx0DfJK0rbCkZrsBOIf0IUEN4uSwZroSOJD0P/3y2CiSgvwROAs4DBv/RnIIoLk2Atex+VyBA7AglJpgDfBh4FXAtdjd31gOAajf3sD7Sbt8Saqni4C/Ae6JDqJ4FgAa7HjgozhRUKqTm0hDfm7mo6fZ5avBLgMOBt4E3BecRVJ37gHOJO0DYuOvLdgDoJGMJxUC/4xHDktV8jipJ+8TpDF/aSsWAGrFVOCvgL8DZgVnkTS8J4HPAB8EVgRnUclZAKgd04F3knYK2yY4i6TN+hv+DwNLg7OoIiwA1AkLAakcbPjVMQsAdWMWcDZpWdHs4CxSk/yJNL7/X7iZlzpkAaAsTCRtKvL/gL2Cs0h19gjpdM/zsOGXVCI9wMnA1aTdxby8vLK57iT1tk1EkkruSOD7QC/xvzy9vKp6XU4qqu2tlVQ5u5LGKlcR/8vUy6sK11rgAtIhPVJurCpVlG1JKwfeBWwXnEUqoyXA54DP9n0t5coCQEWbAJwKvB04Dn8GpYXAF4DzgaeCs6hB/OWrSHsCbwbeCswJziIVaTnwHeBTwK3BWdRQFgAqgynAK0nnDjwPfy5VT5tIB/J8GbgQWB0bR03nL1qVzc7Aa4GzgF2Cs0hZeAj4BvDfwF3BWaSnWQCorHqAE4A3kOYMTIuNI7XlSeAHpHH9XwAbY+NIW7MAUBVMYstiYEJsHGlIvcAVpEb/f4GVsXGkkVkAqGrmAK8AzgCOAcaGplHTbQCuJK3b/x7wRGgaqQ0WAKqy2cBJpGLghdgzoGL0AtcC3wW+jWv2VVEWAKqLWaQtU08hFQMzYuOoZlYAlwA/An6MB/GoBiwAVEdjgSNIvQOnAM+OjaOK+gNwGXARqfFfFxtHypYFgJpgb+BE0kTCo4GpsXFUUiuBq4BLgYuB38fGkfJlAaCmmQD8OakYeCFwIE4kbKpe4Ebg56RG/xr8lK8GsQBQ000DDgeOIh1h/Dw8c72ueoGbgQXA1aT1+c7aV2NZAEhbmkbqITiSVBgcBswMTaROLQOuI83Yv5r0CX9VaCKpRCwApJH1kOYQHEYqCA4F9gXGR4bSVtYDt7G5wb8OuJ20/76kIVgASO0bTzrJ8OC+ax/gINK+BMrfSuAOYBHpKN3+y6N0pTZYAEjZ2YFUDOw74HE/YHpkqApbC9xN+mS/aMDjYtxbX+qaBYCUrzHATsDuwG59j/1f74bFwQrSevu7+q67B3z9EHbhS7mxAJBibUMqEOaTjkLeqe9xB2AeMLfv6okK2KGNwGN91xLgj8ADfdeDwH19Xy+LCig1nQWAVH5j2VwIzCXNNZg1xDWF1KMwCZhM2vBoAmkVw8ACov/PB3oKWDPgnzeStrtdR5o5v5rUJf9k39fLBlxLBzz2N/qPYje9VGr/H2+pGhQmaeVFAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC');
        var element1 = document.getElementById("top");
        element1.appendChild(news);
  }
    function stop(){
        document.getElementById("frame").src = "";
        document.getElementById("stop").remove();
        var neww = document.createElement("img");
        neww.setAttribute('id', 'imgs');
        neww.setAttribute('onclick', 'start();');
        neww.setAttribute('class', 'button');
        neww.setAttribute('src', 'data:image/png;base64,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');
        var element = document.getElementById("center");
        element.appendChild(neww);
    }
```

```css
.border{
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
margin: 2em auto;
position: relative;
z-index: 9999999999;
}
    .freeway{
width: 500px;
height: 400px;
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
border: 2px solid #801edb;
border-radius: 50px;
border-width: thick;
}
.show{
 display: block;
}
.container {
 position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
z-index: -1;
}
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.button {
 cursor: pointer;
 border: none;
}
.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 11px;
  right: 40px;
}
```

```html
<section class="games">
    <div class="border">
  <div class="container">
      <iframe src="" id="frame" class="freeway"></iframe>
       <div id="top" class="top-right"></div>
      <div id="center" class="centered">
        <img class="button" src="data:image/png;base64,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" onclick="start();" id="imgs"/>
      </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</section>
 <script>
 window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
 // space and arrow keys
 if([32, 37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(e.keyCode) > -1) {
    e.preventDefault();
 }
 }, false);
 </script>
```

Try this!

Comment: Hey there. 
First of all, thank you so much for this. I did some minors adaptations and replicated it for a second game and it worked fine. 

There are 2 litle problems tho:
1- While playing when you use the directional arrows, they will also move the scroll bar and move the page screen.
2- It does not stop. Anyone one who gets in the page and wants to play both games will need to refresh the page to stop the first one.

Do you have any solutions for these? 

Once again, thank you for your help.

Comment: Yes I do. Do you what a stop button or a pause button?

Comment: Try that! Added stop button! and no arrow key scrolling during game.

Comment: Also, this is how I set up the games with the code you first sent me:

https://imgur.com/a/b6WR4xz

and here are the little changes I made and adaptations for a second game:
https://imgur.com/a/ahV1dEP

Comment: and what does this do?

".show{
 display: block;
}"

Comment: The stop button did the trick. Its great. But the arrows are still moving the whole page. Can't play if the page is going up and down. hehe. I think the way I said before made you understand that what was moving was the game screen. I'm learning a lot with your help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you send me a link to your page?

Comment: It is not hosted yet, I does not have a link.

Comment: Try what I added.

Comment: Will try it right now. 

You asked the link to the page before, does this help? :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vA11bL1nvhcPYHXRYNBmDzBDxaRs7ZMR/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Access Denied. The the link. **60013695@ironschools.org** use email.

Comment: Its done. 
I think its funny how it suggest us to use a chat, but it dont allow me to chat since I dont have reputation. If its not a trouble for you, would you mind to use discord?

Comment: page still going up and down.

Comment: Are you using a local host?

Comment: "For if you have move work to do?" Sorry, I did not understand what you meant.
And I'm just editing the code on Visual Studio and opening with opera to see the changes.

Comment: You are using opera I would use chrome.

Comment: Here this should work copy this and paste it. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sYB5Q2BRwzyfh8ja8FbJ86GqdvPNOo2S/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I do have it installed. The results are the same.

Comment: Try the link above. I edited your file so I sould work

Comment: Same thing. when you play the game, the page moves up and down.

Comment: lol... it works when you are not playing the game. Start the game, click on the game screen and play it. It will move. If you try to move without doing it it,  it will actually works.  But the objective is to hold the page still while playing. hehe.

Comment: The page loads, you can move the srocll bar with arrows. you click on the game to start it, it does lock the sroll bar, but you cant control the cow, then you need to lick in the game again to be able to move the cow. When you to it, the scroll bar gets unlocked. If you click pause button, the scroll bar will lock again.

Comment: I am looking how to fix this

Comment: will update code from here:https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oowru3H0thzQ46llr6RBKCbWf6uBUcfho138JUqRIzE/edit

Comment: Its happening the same thing.

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: I think I'm taking to much of your time. Thank you for your efforts, but maybe I should go in an other way with this part.

Comment: look here for more help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916620/disable-arrow-key-scrolling-in-users-browser