# React: How to navigate through list in a table by arrow keys without triggering the scrollbar moving up and down?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have built a table component with a list of items in it. By defining hotkeys with the react-hotkeys package, I can navigate through the list with the 'arrow up' and 'arrow down' keys. However, I do have a scroll bar on the right side of the screen. Whenever I use the hotkeys, the screen will scroll at the same time. How can I navigate through items with the hotkey without triggering the scrollbar unless the item is out of the current screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily prevent the default browser scroll behavior on the event keydown when the key is arrow up or arrow down. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916620/disable-arrow-key-scrolling-in-users-browser) explains how to do this.

For your specific needs to disable / enable it whether the table is in the viewport or not, you could check if it is in the event.

```
const table = document.querySelector('#table-id')

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if(["Space","ArrowUp","ArrowDown","ArrowLeft","ArrowRight"].indexOf(e.code) > -1) {
        const y = table.getBoundingClientRect().y
        if (y > 0 && y < window.innerHeight) { // Table is in viewport.
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}, false);
```