# What are the key codes for the right and left arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What are the key codes for the right and left arrow keys?

Comment: the right and left navigation key...u know..u got up, left, right, down on your keyboard

Comment: [See this please](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/c4/702b8cd1-e5b0-42e6-83ac-25f0306e3e25/Javascript-Char-Codes-Key-Codes.aspx)

Comment: "arrow" was the word you were looking for.

Comment: haha .. sorry didnt know the word "pile" wasnt english...its translated to arrow i think..

Comment: I've fixed it. (What language is "pile"? I know it's "batteries" in Italian, but that's about it...)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492865/jquery-keypress-event-not-firing

Comment: If the answer helped, maybe mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 38):

Left: 37, Right: 39.

Discovery of other keycodes can be done with the following code:

```
$('body').keyup(function (event) {
  console.log(event.keyCode);
});
```

Which will output the keycode to the console when you press any key.

Answer (score 11):

left key - 37

right key - 39