# Selecting textbox value when pressing the next button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a grid of textboxes.  When the user presses the arrow button I need the cursor to select the contents of the textbox in the direction they have just pushed.  I have tried using JQuery's .select() method, but this doesnt seem to work in IE.

Could you give me suggestions on how to get this working?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can someone fix the right and left here?
Up and down does the trick, navigating inside the textboxes seem to take precedense

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>test tab</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkKey(e){
     switch (e.keyCode) {
        case 40:
            current = $("#field1"); 
            $("#msg").html(current.id); 
            setTimeout('focusIt()',100);
            break;
        case 38:
            current = $("#field3"); // or some more clever way of finding the last field
            $("#msg").html(current.id); 
            setTimeout('focusIt()',100);
            break;
        case 37:
            if (prev) current = prev;
            else current = $("#field3"); // or some more clever way of finding the last field
            $("#msg").html(current.id); 
            setTimeout('focusIt()',100);
            break;
        case 39:
            if (next) current = next; 
            else current = $("#field1")
            $("#msg").html(current.id); 
            setTimeout('focusIt()',100);
            break;
        default:

            }      
}
function focusIt() {
  if(current) {current.focus(); current.select() }
}
var current,next,prev;
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($.browser.mozilla) {
    $("input").keypress (checkKey);
  } else {
    $("input").keydown (checkKey);
  }
  $("input").focus(function() {
    current=this;
    $("#msg").html(current.id);
    next = $("field"+(parseInt(current.id.replace('field',''))+1));
    prev = $("field"+(parseInt(current.id.replace('field',''))-1));
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pagecontent" style="width:95%; margin:10px 10px 10px 10px">
   <form>
   <input type="text" id="field1" value="first"/><input type="text" id="field2" value="second"/><input type="text" id="field3" value="third"/>
   </form>
   <span id="msg"></span>   
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the text box's `select()` method, which works in all major scriptable browsers, so long as you've focussed it first:

```
<input type="text" id="aTextBox" value="Some text">
<script type="text/javascript">
    var textBox = document.getElementById("aTextBox");
    textBox.focus();
    textBox.select();
</script>
```

Comment: I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492865/jquery-keypress-event-not-firing

Comment: Right, when pressing arrow, fine. I inferred (possibly incorrectly) from the question that that was not the problem and was incidental. The bit that seemed to be the problem was the selection: *"I have tried using JQuery's .select() method, but this doesnt seem to work in IE."*

Comment: Tim you were correct.  The issue was the selecting of the text in the textbox.  The pressing of the arrow was incidental.  I was trying togive some informatino around what I was doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="aTextBox" value="Some text">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#TextBox').focus().select();
</script>
```

Try using both of them in one line

Comment: Thanks Robert I did try them on one line but it didnt seem to work.