# Redirect to another page Javascript

Tags: javascript

Im trying to redirect to another page when user hits return.But its not working:

```
$(function() {
    $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPopCEP").keypress(function(e) {
        var tecla = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keycode;

        if (tecla == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            window.location.href = "http://www.chinainbox.com.br/site2010/lojaBuscaResultado.aspx?cep=" + $(this).text() + "&pop=yes";
            // __doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ImageButton1', '');
        }
    });
});
```

Any ideias?

Comment: I am not sure if this solves it. But try `return false` after window.location.href.

Comment: Nice,now it works in FF but not in IE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line...

```
var tecla = (e.which) ? e.which : e.keycode;
```

Is not needed.  jQuery takes care of this cross-browser issue.  Also, the "c" in `keycode` must be captialized, and that is all you need to fix...

```
var tecla = e.keyCode;
```

Comment: @user257234 I wouldn't have taken the time to answer if I was not sure

Comment: @user257234 You might want to try `keyup` instead of `keypress`.  In the jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/keypress/) they mention issues with using keypress in combination with keycode.

Comment: @Stefan What part does not work in 1.3.2?  I thought the handling of e.which goes way back.

Comment: Nope. Go read through the bug reports. Enter, tab, delete, and some other characters have issues and don't work right.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks for the link...  I think those issues are related to the keypress event, which I already mentioned in a previous comment.

Comment: I don't think this is explicitly on keypress, but I wouldn't compromise design to fix bugs. I'd say "upgrade to 1.4.2" is a better suggestion, but you should at least mention the caveat. Not everyone can run 1.4.2 due to existing environment constraints.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I guess the inconsistency is in FF for keycode. http://api.jquery.com/keypress/ Read the comments. `e.which` is supposed to be normalized.

Answer (score 1):

**update:** as pointed out by Stefan Kendall in the comments, the following only applies to jQuery versions < 1.4.3

---

Looks like it should work -- have you tested to ensure the event is firing? Keypress is supposedly not very reliable, you should try switching to keydown or keyup

See the question [jquery kepress event not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492865/jquery-keypress-event-not-firing)

Answer (score 0):

try doing `window.location` instead of `window.location.href`.

Comment: This isn't the answer to the question, and it's not even correct stand-alone on top of that.

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be using `window.location=` instead of `window.location.href=`