# EnterKey is not working sometimes in IE8, using jQuery's keyPressed

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8

In my HTML
css:

```
.edit_field {
    height: 50px;
    width: 495px;
    line-height: 3.6;
}
```

html:

```
<textarea id="message" class='edit_field'>Enter message here</textarea>
```

javascrpt:

```
$('#message').keypress(function(event) {
    // not getting fired this block when I pressed enter key
    // For all other keys its got fired well.
    if(event.which == 13) {
        // -- -- --
     }
});
```

Is there any problem in my code or in my browser(IE8)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#message').keyup(function(e){
  if(e.keyCode == 13){
    //your code probably want e.preventDefault() as well
  }
});
```

I've found keypress implementation to not be so cross-browser friendly. Just a thought.

**Edit**: 
I now remember why this doesn't work in IE8. The enter key (keycode 13) is considered a "Special Key" (as well as others like arrow keys on the keyboard) IE does NOT fire a keypress event for "Special Keys" which is why I had to use keyup.

You can find more info here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/keys.html

Look under "Special Keys"

Answer (score 3):

e.which doesn't work in IE try e.keyCode, also you probably want to use keydown() instead of keypress() if you are targeting IE.

See http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html for more information.

---

[jQuery keypress() event not firing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492865/jquery-keypress-event-not-firing)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this too, particularly with tables using an onKeyDown() in IE7.  Other keys fire fine but enter is tricky.  I solved mine by moving my onkeydown() trigger about in the HTML, from certain locations it wouldnt pick up enter but would gather others.

If I recall I had it originally in the body tag and moving it to a `<div>` just inside the body immediately allowed me to detect enter.  I was using jsp with a switch but I dont think its a great deal different