# Contenteditable : detect the node I am in when I press enter key in IE

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, contenteditable

In a contenteditable element, When pressing the enter key, I am trying to detect if the line where I press enter is an li tag.

I did the following code which works fine in Firefox and chrome :

```
$("div[contenteditable=true]").on('keydown', function(e) {

    if( e.keyCode === 13 ) {

        if (window.getSelection) { 

            var node = document.getSelection().anchorNode;

            var nodeName = node.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase();

            if(nodeName == 'li') {

                console.log(" I am an <li> ");
            }

     }

}
```

I am wondering how to do that with Internet explorer ?

Comment: What is `Console`? Did you mean `console`?

Comment: Which IE? Which part isn't working?

Comment: @PaulS. it was just a typo, corrected it thanks!

Comment: Try using `keyup` http://stackoverflow.com/a/5204776/1305911