# Keypress() not working in IE 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, keypress

My jQuery code not working in IE 9 but work well in IE7, IE8, Chrome, FF.

This is my code:

```
$(document).keypress(function(){
        window.clearTimeout();
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            //Do something...
            return false;
        }, 800);
});
```

Comment: It could be a lack of `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Comment: What is the point of calling clearTimeout without a timeoutid? it shouldn't do anything in that case (and i suspect that's where your issue is)

Comment: Thanks, but my site is not lack of it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `window.clearTimeout()` or give it a parameter. IE9 [incorrectly requires](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/timers.html#dom-windowtimers-cleartimeout) it.

```
$(document).keypress(function(){
    //window.clearTimeout();
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Worky!");
        return false;
    }, 800);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Hztuv/1/

or

```
var timeout;
$(document).keypress(function(){
    window.clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Worky!");
        return false;
    }, 800);
});
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for help! I was missing `timeout`.

Answer (score 3):

Try switching to keydown, which is different to the computer, but should achieve the same effect

From a tutorial:

> In order to understand the difference between keydown and keypress, it is useful to understand the difference between a "character" and a "key". A "key" is a physical button on the computer's keyboard while a "character" is a symbol typed by pressing a button.  In theory, the keydown and keyup events represent keys being pressed or released, while the keypress event represents a character being typed. The implementation of the theory is not same in all browsers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried but it not working. I using the jquery code for affect like Google search input on home search page. When i typing anything words, some results is showing below.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492865/jquery-keypress-event-not-firing) is better to use `keydown()` instead of `keypress()` on IE